# Contingency table in Python

Tags: python, statistics

Given two lists of equal length, how can I construct a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table#Example) in a truly pythonic way?
I know about confusion_matrix from [skit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), but are there 'manual' and effective ways to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pandas library to create the table shown in the wikipedia example, like so,

```
import pandas as pd
right_handed = [43, 44]
left_handed = [9,4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'right': right_handed, 'left': left_handed}, index = ['males', 'females'])
```

This yields a DataFrame, like so,

```
In [3]:

print (df)

         left  right
males       9     43
females     4     44
```

You can then use sum to get the totals,

```
print (df.left.sum())    
print (df.right.sum())

13
87

In [7]:

print (df.ix['males'].sum())
print (df.ix['females'].sum())

52
48
```